# Free space on /boot disk problem

Tags: boot

I have an Asus u6sg and when I have to install updates It tell me that I do not have enough space in the "/boot" disk. I can't be able to do changes with Gparted.

How can I do?

thanks

PS: how can I insert here a screenshot saved in my Image folder?

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the size of your /boot partition you must run *gparted* from a "live DVD" or "Live USB". (You can use the one you've used to install the system). So:

- Boot from "Live  DVD" or "Live USB". (Make sure how your BIOS choose the device priority and arrange the device where your image is to boot)
- Run gparted and make the changes you want. (Size in your case). Check everything thoroughly to avoid mistakes.
- Restart your computer removing the media you used for the live session when prompted. (If necessary revert your BIOS to the prior Boot priority).

**Note:** *It is advisable to backup your data before messing with your system.*